# JSON file not loading on Chrome or Internet Exploror

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm creating a jQuery web mobile application. It work fine on Firefox, but when running on Internet Explorer or Google Chrome it shows error:  `json file not load`

```
$.getJSON('menu.json', function(menu) {
    var processedTemplate = $.mustache($("#menuTemplate").html(),    menu.menu);
    $list.html(processedTemplate);
});
// .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
// alert("error " + textStatus + " incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
// });
.error(function() { alert("Sorry can't load JSON file locally in this browser!")});
```

Comment: Remove `;` from 4th line of your code.